# images added into resx file

Tags: c#, resx

This has been a interesting file for me.
I found that ,whenever a image is added to this ,the image is actually converted into bytes and stored as data rather than a file.
I just want to know the benefit of this?also will be there be chances of bytes getting curropted when the file is put into version control(Most unlikely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is nothing else but data written to disk and usually contains the actual data plus some header information (e.g. image type, so you know how to interprete the data). If it helps you understand it, think of the resx file as a "mini" file system from which the image data can be retrieved.

If put in version control, resx files should be no problem.

Comment: johannes,my question was whether there is any benifit of having images in this way ?

Comment: yes. You save yourself from writing the loading code for your resources as it is automatically generated by VS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx).